# Powershell, move cursor in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell

I have the following code to search for a certain value in Excel and replace it with "Test". It works perfectly.

After the value has been replaced i want to move the cursor to the next cell on the right and save that value as a variable, for example "$Var1".

I didn't find a way to move the cursor with PowerShell. Can anybody help?

```
$File = "D:\Exel\List.xlsx"

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($file)
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item("KDList")

$SearchString = "11312"

$Range = $Worksheet.Range("B1").EntireColumn
$Search = $Range.find($SearchString)

$Search.value() = "Test"
```

Comment: You use the same MSExcel OM and language to do that as you have already for the other aspects of what you did. You can open any MSExcel doc, start the macro records, use the GUI to click the steps, and read the code it creates to refactor as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following 2 lines at the end of your code:

```ps
$Worksheet.Cells($Search.Row, $Search.Column + 1).Select()
$Var1 = $Worksheet.Cells.Item($Search.Row, $Search.Column + 1)
```

The first line selects the cell at the right of the search value was found and replaced. The second line sets the value of the selected cell to the variable `$Var1`

In case you want to check/display the value of `$Var1`, use `$Var1.Text`:

```ps
Write-Host $Var1.Text
```

Comment: Yup, that was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you Reddy!